# How to get integer value in Y-axis in Jqplot?

Tags: jqplot

In chart I want to get integer values on Y-axis and X-axis in place of decimal value (1 in place of 1.0).

so please give me solution

I have used this...
    "axes: { 
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    ticks: ticks,

```
                tickOptions: 
                 { formatString: '%d'
                 }
                }

            }"
```

Comment: please share full code of jqplot

Answer (score 0):

Try this `formatString: "%.0f"`. This will display whole numbers.